# Using magnific popup lightbox with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I'm using jQuery plugin [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) to display additional content as a simple lightbox on every acticles preview from my website.

The first popup works however all the other instances open the first instance content.

Knowing that the article list/popup numbers displayed on the same page is not fixed.

Is there any way to differentiate every popup from the same page ?

HTML

```
<a id="pop" class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog">More content</a>

<div id="small-dialog" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
.. PHP generated content ..
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
  type: 'inline',   
  fixedContentPos: false,
  fixedBgPos: true,      
  overflowY: 'auto',
  closeBtnInside: true,
  preloader: true,            
  midClick: true,
  removalDelay: 300,
  mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to do it. For anyone reading this :

You just have to make a unique name for every popup.

```
<a id="pop" class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#unique-variable">More content</a>

<div id="unique-variable" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
.. PHP generated content ..
</div>
```